# Generating reactive feedbackWarnings for dynamically generated input with Shiny

Tags: r, validation, shiny, reactive, renderui

Shiny beginner here! I'm trying to create an app, where the user can input a dynamic number of 8-digit codes. First they input the number of codes they like, and using renderUI, that many slots are generated.

I would like to use ShinyFeedback to check the nchar for each inserted code, and show a warning if it is not 8 digits. This is what I have so far for:

```
  code_check <- reactive({

    lapply(1:input$numInputs, function(i) {

      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning(input$inputName,
                                     nchar(input$inputName) != 8,
                                     "Your code needs to be 8 digits!")
    }

    )
  })
```

I am having trouble accessing the individual inputs by their id. The input$inputName is generated in the renderUI section:

```
  observeEvent(input$numInputs, {
    
    output$inputGroup = renderUI({
      
      input_list <- lapply(1:input$numInputs, function(i) {
        
        # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
        inputName <- paste("Code ", i, sep = " ")
        
        # generate the input field, the inputID = label, initial value is 12345678
        textInput(inputName, inputName, "12345678")
        
      })
      
      })
    
    })
```

Running this code give the following error: `Warning: Error in feedback: is.character(inputId) is not TRUE`

Complete current code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
  
  titlePanel("As many 8 digit codes as you like"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("numInputs", "How many codes would you like to insert?", 4),
      # place to hold dynamic inputs
      uiOutput("inputGroup")
    ),

    mainPanel(textOutput("inputValues"),
              textOutput("final"),
              textOutput("code_check")
              
    )
    
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  # observe changes in "numInputs", and create corresponding number of inputs

  observeEvent(input$numInputs, {
    
    output$inputGroup = renderUI({
      
      input_list <- lapply(1:input$numInputs, function(i) {
        
        # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
        inputName <- paste("Code ", i, sep = " ")
        
        # generate the input field, the inputID = label, initial value is 12345678
        textInput(inputName, inputName, "12345678")
        
      })
      
      })
    
    })

  code_check <- reactive({

    lapply(1:input$numInputs, function(i) {

      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning(input$inputName,
                                     nchar(input$inputName) != 8,
                                     "Your code needs to be 8 digits!")
    }

    )
  })
  
  output$code_check <- renderPrint({code_check()})
  
  test <- reactive({
    paste(lapply(1:input$numInputs, function(i) {
      
      inputName <- paste("Code ", i, sep = " ")
      input[[inputName]]
    }))
  })

output$final <- renderPrint({test()})
  
  observe({
    assign(
      x = "inserted_codes",
      value =  test(),
      envir = .GlobalEnv
    )
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Would be grateful for any ideas :)

Comment: There are several problems. You define `inputName` in the `renderUI`, and it does not go beyond this scope. Outside this `renderUI`, `inputName` does not exist. Next you put a white space in an input id, which is not acceptable. And in your `lapply`  you have a function of `i`, but `i` does not appear in the body of the function. And `input$inputName` is `NULL`, that's why you get this error from `shinyFeedback`.

Comment: But is there any way to reach the inputName-s generated in the renderUI?